# Include figure (from macro) with underscore in filename

Tags: external-files, automation, naming

I have a system of where a `.tex` is generated from a program. The final `.tex` file has a (simplified) structure like this:

```
\newcommand{\PlotFrame}[1]{%
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{...}
...
...
\includegraphics{#1}
\end{frame}}



\PlotFrame{File_1.png}
\PlotFrame{File_2.png}
...
\PlotFrame{File_n.png}
```

Now - when compiling this with `pdflatex` it complains at `\PlotFrame{File_n.png}` statements; because of the underscore. Unfortunately I do not have control over the filenames. Any suggestions of how I could keep the current structure with the `\PlotFrame{}` command - and let it accept arguments with underscore?

I would *strongly* prefer not having to escape it with `\_`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/5764) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Comment: For me, underscores in filenames work without problems. Can you post a Minimal Working Example?

Comment: In a minimal example with your code I get the image even if the name contains an underscore. Please, add a real example of something that causes the error. It probably has to do with *printing* the file name, rather than including the file.

Comment: Ahhh - this was embarassing; it turns out the problem was not with filename as such - but the figure caption which basically said: \caption{File: #1}

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can define an additional macro like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\PlotFrameB}[1]{%
\includegraphics{#1}\endgroup}

\def\PlotFrame{\begingroup 
\catcode`\_=12
\PlotFrameB}

\begin{document}


\PlotFrame{File_1.png}
\PlotFrame{File_2.png}
...
\PlotFrame{File_n.png}

\[ a_b \]

\end{document}
```

This will temporarily change the catcode for `_` in the argument.

Comment: The solution based on \catcode worked - thanks a lot!