# Syntax error; pgfuseimage

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, syntax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Include figure (from macro) with underscore in filename](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69142/include-figure-from-macro-with-underscore-in-filename)

I am trying to make first presentation in LaTeX using **Beamer** environment. In order to include some graphics, I choose **pgf** package since it is automatically loaded with Beamer.

I was trying to put a simple picture but my attempt failed. I tried to make it as simple as possible to find out where I am doing the mistake but I did not succeed.

I was following this manual: [TikZ & PGF Manual for Version 2.10](http://ctan.ijs.si/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf)

I am using MikTeX ver 0.4.3. r.857, Beamer from 2012-04-17, Pgf from 2011-11-05.

Code:

```
\documentclass[slidestop,cmpress,mathsefir,red]{beamer}
\usetheme{sidebar}
\usecolortheme{dove}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{green}
\pgfdeclareimage[width=3cm]{Transmitlogo}{transmit_round}
\begin{document}
\section*{Outline}
\frame {
    \pgfuseimage{Transmitlogo}
    \frametitle{Outline}
    \tableofcontents
}
\end{document}
```

If I comment `\pgfuseimage{Transmitlogo}` everything works OK. Keeping the line I am getting error:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
            $
l.38 }
```

line 38 is the line with the frame ending `}`.

Thanks for any hit.

Comment: your file name has underscore which triggers TeX to look for math mode context like `$a_i$`.

Comment: Please, put your text as an answer, it works just fine. Such a trivial mistake, thx. So it means, that files cannot have `_`inside their names.

Comment: Instead may I suggest to close this as too localized or a duplicate? It's indeed a minor issue and would serve better to point to a better answer.

Comment: Sure, probably no one will use it in the future.

Comment: @percusse The trick in the linked question/answer does not work here, which is a very different problem, not involving `\includegraphics`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a misfeature of the `\pgfdeclareimage` macro, that absorbs the file name without taking precautions about characters which should be allowed in file names, such as the underscore.

However the PGF/TikZ manual states that `\includegraphics` is preferable (see section 79.1), so use

```
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{transmit_round}
```

and you'll experiment no problem.

---

In case you prefer to get along with `\pgfuseimage`, a possible fix, which will also allow to include macros in the file name (for denoting in an abstract way a directory, for example) is the following

```
\documentclass[slidestop,cmpress,mathsefir,red]{beamer}
\usetheme{sidebar}
\usecolortheme{dove}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{green}

%%% PATCH STARTS
\makeatletter
\let\original@pgf@declareimage\pgf@declareimage
\def\pgf@declareimage[#1]#2#3{%
  \def\temppatch@declareimage{\original@pgf@declareimage[#1]{#2}}%
  \edef\temppatch@declareimagearg{#3}%
  \expandafter\temppatch@declareimage\expandafter{\detokenize\expandafter{\temppatch@declareimagearg}}%
}
\makeatother
%%% PATCH ENDS    

\newcommand{\mygraphics}{figures}

\pgfdeclareimage[width=3cm]{Transmitlogo}{transmit_round}
\pgfdeclareimage[width=3cm]{try}{\mygraphics/abc_def}

\begin{document}
\section*{Outline}
\frame {
    \pgfuseimage{Transmitlogo}
    \frametitle{Outline}
    \tableofcontents
}

\frame{\pgfuseimage{try}}
\end{document}
```

The file in the `figures` subdirectory is correctly found.

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you. You prevented me from renaming a lot of picture names!