# Inkscape and XeLaTeX and pdf_tex/pdf+tex graphics

Tags: graphics, xetex, revtex

How XeLaTeX can be used to include pdf_tex graphics files produced from svg files including amstex code and exported with Inkscape (v48.2) with the PADF+LaTeX option? (the problem occurs independently of the pdf_tex file chosen). I use TeXShop v2.47 and MacTeX and TeX-Live 2013.

A MWE:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% !TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX   
% !TEX encoding = MacOSRoman    
%%%%%%%%%%%%% PREAMBLE %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%   
\documentclass[aps,pra,12pt]{revtex4-1}   
\usepackage[no-sscript]{xltxtra}    
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amscd,stmaryrd}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern,textcomp,url}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx} 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}

See Figure. 

\begin{figure}[ht] 
\centering 
\def\svgwidth{\columnwidth} 
\input{figure.pdf_tex}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I obtain the following indications when compiling the tex file:

```
................
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/stmaryrd/Ustmry.fd))
No file test.bbl.
[1]
./test.tex:35: Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \aftergroup 
l.35 \end{document}
```

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

@DavidCarlisle

Here is again the tex file:

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% !TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX
\documentclass[aps,pra,12pt]{revtex4-1} 
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel} 
%\usepackage{xltxtra} 
%\usepackage{polyglossia} 
%\setmainlanguage{english} 
%\setotherlanguage{french} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsmath,amscd} 
\usepackage{lmodern,textcomp,url} 
\usepackage{color} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
See Figure. 
\begin{figure}[ht] 
\centering 
\def\svgwidth{.75\columnwidth} 
\input{Figure.pdf_tex}
\end{figure}
\end{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

It works fine. But during the compilation the following message is given (the content of the input line 26 is the \begin{document} command):

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

Package frenchb.ldf Warning: Add \usepackage{xltxtra} to the
(frenchb.ldf)                preamble of your document, on input line 26.

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

But, then, if I try to include this package in the tex file, there is a clash with the following indication:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

 (/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd))
 No file test.bbl.
[1]    
./test.tex:37: Missing number, treated as zero.    
<to be read again> 
                  \aftergroup 
   l.37 \end{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

Using the package polyglossia alone (without xltxtra and babel as well) does not work. So?

Comment: Which line in the file is actually line 35? Perhaps it is the underscore in the file name? See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69142/include-figure-from-macro-with-underscore-in-filename for information on how you can include/input files whose name contains an underscore.

Comment: @Ruedi The line 35 contains only the \end{document} command. 
It cannot be due to the underscore in the file name since the file works correctly but only without the xltxtra package. 
But this package is required if I want to use babel with the english or frenchb option for instance (this xltxtra package must be added as indicated during the compilation when using the babel package; whatever is the option).

Comment: Please edit the question to include a copy of figure.pdf_tex but _never_ use `inputenc` with xetex or luatex (and using `fontenc` is pretty rare too, normally people use xetex because they want to use system fonts with `fontspec`)

Comment: Note your declarations at the top are incompatible `% !TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX ` and `% !TEX encoding = MacOSRoman ` You can not use 8bit encodings such as MacOSRoman with xetex you must use utf-8 Unicode encoding.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle 

I corrected this encoding with the command 

% !TEX TS-program = UTF-8 Unicode

but the problem remains completely.

It seems to be due to "interactions" between babel and xltxtra. Using 

\usepackage[english]{babel}

alone works fine whereas 

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{xltxtra}

does not.

Comment: What features of xetex do you need? Can't you use pdflatex?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle 

Actually, I use pdflatex. TEXShop is configured by default in the preferences with pdflatex with the shell command: 

pdflatex --file-line-error --shell-escape --synctex=1

I obtain the same difficulties with pdflatex and xelatex engine. 

The problem seems to come from the file fixltx2e.sty required by fontspec.sty launched by xltstra.sty ; I have no certainty.

Substituting the command

\documentclass[aps,pra,12pt]{revtex4-1}

by

\documentclass[12pt]{article}

solves the problem. As you noticed this is a problem between revtex and xelatex. But, I cannot avoid to use revtex.

Comment: No you are using xelatex rather than pdflatex and the fix appears to be to use pdflatex instead. xltxtra and fontspec are xelatex packages that are unusable with pdftex but you don't seem to require any of the xelatex functionality, so using pdftex is presumably the answer.

Answer (score 5):

As noted in comments your input is mixing old style font and encoding handling with xetex. In particular xltxtra loads fontspec (the usual way to specify fonts with xetex) and that appears to be incompatible with revtex. Your example as posted can not be used but this cut down example generates the same error.

```
\documentclass[aps,pra,12pt]{revtex4-1}   
%\usepackage[no-sscript]{xltxtra}    
\usepackage{fontspec}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
See Figure. 

\begin{figure}[ht] 
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

So it seems that you want to either use revtex with pdftex or use a different class with xetex.

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \aftergroup 
l.12 \end{document}
```